# operator overloading error C++

Tags: c++

I have a inline operator overloading in cpp file.
My understanding is the inline function should also put in the header file with the body of function.

but when i do that. the error come out which is 
redefinition of "operator =="

could you explain why is the error like that.
and also, could anyone explain what sorts of content should keep in the header file.?

```
inline bool operator ==(Duration& d1, Duration& d2)
{

   return d1.getSecond() == d2.getSecond();
}
```

Comment: You should add `const` to the parameters: `inline bool operator ==(const Duration& d1, const Duration& d2)`

Answer (score 3):

You can't define a function twice. Declare it in the header and define it in the cpp - OR - just define it in the header and leave it out of the cpp completely.

Comment: A definition in the header should be `inline`, I think, while a definition in the cpp file shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Inline functions need to go in the header, not the source. Otherwise they won't be available in the other sources where you try to call them.

Having a second copy in the source is indeed a duplicate.